# How to synchronise 2 audio files? where one is the recorded version of the other?

Tags: android, audio, wav

I have a wav file playing through my speakers. Now I have recorded the sound playing through my speakers using my mic. At the same bit rate and PCM quality values as the playing file. Now I want to exactly sync these two songs.Say for eg: the 15th PCM value in the song playing through the speaker was recorded as the 5th PCM value. I want to detect this and sync the song accordingly. Complexity is not much a concern and I need to do this without human intervention. I know there would be noise and the values wont be the same but I need to just sync these two songs so they play exactly superimpose. I am using mono,16BIt PCM value with a bit rate of 44100.

Answer (score 0):

Because of noise, distortion, echos and other delays, there is no simple solution for your problem. However, generally speaking, the solution to this type of problem is to use [Cross Correlation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) Broadly speaking, the peak in the cross-correlation will tell you the delay between the two signals.

Comment: Could you please elaborate and provide some research articles relating to that.

Comment: The wikipedia article I linked provides several links to research articles which elaborate on the subject. For example, section 6.6 here discusses using cross-correlation to measure the time-difference of a white noise signal: http://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/oliver.hinton/eee305/Chapter6.pdf